# No data, only a table header when rendering first time the 'products#index' page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

I am using `Rails 4` and `DataTables 1.10.7` following the `Rails Cast #340` to test a small `Products` application.

Here is my entire code: https://github.com/levi-l-damian/test-dt-mg.
Everything works very well with one exception, first time I am entering the Products Index page, the page has no table body rendered, only a header.
But if I refresh the page data appears and it is present no matter how I am playing with the table, searching, sorting, etc.

However after I am visiting other pages and I am coming back to the Products Index, again, no data in the table.

Don't know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the coffee script (not sure why this is not working) and moved exactly the same lines in a Java script at the bottom of the index page.
Problem solved, here is the script used in the index page (after commenting our the coffee script line):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#products').dataTable({
      sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
      bJQueryUI: true,
      bProcessing: true,
      bServerSide: true,
      sAjaxSource: $('#products').data('source'),
      sDom: 'CRlfrtip'
    })
  } );
</script>
```

I also updated accordingly the code in the `Github` link for the code if someone will be interested to take a look.